# How to texture a VBO?

Tags: textures, shaders, vbo, jogl

I'm not sure which way is the best way to do this for my purposes.
My purposes being having a textured (with an image) cube.

Also, I've been following a blend of tutorials, so I'm not sure which way is the most right and what I'm doing wrong (currently I haven't had the texture fit right).

1. Do I use glDrawArrays or glDrawElements?
2. For pointers, do I say `gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);` and `gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureData);`
   or
   `gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);` and `gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);`
3. When do I bind/unbind the buffers? (`gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertices); gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTextureCoordHandle);`) Before I establish the pointers or not in my drawing method at all?
4. Do I need to specify the UV coordinates/Texture Coordinates in the shader? If I'm getting a weirdly stretched texture, does that mean my fragment shader and setting the uniforms is working correctly?

Thank you!
I can supply more code, but I think I just need more information on the basics.

Comment: You really should consider reading different tutorial.

Comment: There are so many tutorials out there, but none of them fit my exact situation, so I've been reading several and have found they are not all consistent: now I have this problem of not knowing what to take away from each tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Depends whether you use indices(elements) or not (arrays).
2. niether, you should use gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, stride, (const GLvoid *)      offsetOfFirst), unless you lib overrides it ofcourse.
3. no idea, sorry, I use attributes
4. means you pass wrong UVs. To shader you pass only sample location. (make sure UVs are in range 0.0 - 1.0)
5. you really should find alternative tutorial if you dont understand part of one

Comment: *please correct me if I am wrong at any statement*